# Durability of CXF configurations performed using HttpConduit and HttpClientPolicy

Tags: soap, jax-ws, cxf

I'm configuring CXF using the HttpConduit and HttpClientPolicy. Right now every request sees the following customisations:

```
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(queryService);
    client.getRequestContext().put(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, server);
    HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    policy.setConnectionTimeout(timeout * 1000);
    policy.setReceiveTimeout(timeout * 1000);

    if (AUTHENTICATION_TYPE_NTLM.equals(authenticationType))
        policy.setAllowChunking(false);

    if (authenticationCookie != null)
        policy.setCookie(authenticationCookie.toString());

    conduit.setClient(policy);
```

Are these customisations something which can be applied once, when the `queryService` instance is created? If that is the case, how can I set the authentication cookie independently for each request?